# adding a class current in the navigation category with php

Tags: php, class

I Have page containe posts i can filter those posts with php passing a value in url for included page , I want to add current class on a tag for the current category replacing another class with php . this is my code for the moment :

```
<div class="top_p_r" style="width:825px; float:left;">
    <span class="cat">Category</span>
    <ul class="ul_cat_blog">
    <?php
    echo'<li class="li_cat_blog"><a class="current" href="/">All</a></li>';
    foreach(Categorie::getAllCategorie()as $categorie ){
    $categorie= new Categorie($categorie->ID_CAT);
    echo '<li class="li_cat_blog"><a class="rotated_link" href="?cat='.$categorie->getIDCategorie().'">'.$categorie->getNomCategorie().'</a></li>';}?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to use the value witch i pass in url in order to change the class="rotated_link" to class="current" , i try like this but it doesn't work with me it show always the class='rotated_link' :

```
<div class="top_p_r" style="width:825px; float:left;">
    <span class="cat">Category</span>
    <ul class="ul_cat_blog">
    <?php 
     $currentPath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
     $currentClass = ' class="current"'; 
     $rotatesdClass = ' class="rotated_link"'; ?>
   <?php
   echo'<li class="li_cat_blog"><a class="current" href="/">All</a></li>';
    foreach(Categorie::getAllCategorie()as $categorie ){
        $categorie= new Categorie($categorie->ID_CAT);

        echo '<li class="li_cat_blog"><a'; if( $currentPath == $id_categorie ) { echo $currentClass; } else {echo $rotatesdClass;} echo' href="?cat='.$categorie->getIDCategorie().'">'.$categorie->getNomCategorie().'</a></li>';
    }?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: what is $id_categorie ? do you mean it should be $categorie?

Comment: $id_categorie = $_GET["cat"]; is the value wich i pass in URL when i choose category

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overwriting your own variable:

```
foreach(Categorie::getAllCategorie()as $categorie ){
    $categorie = new Categorie($categorie->ID_CAT);
```

Here, you are over-riding the value of `$categorie`.